# Error trying to load Google APIs

Tags: javascript, google-api, ecmascript-6

I'm using `JSPM`, `ES6`, `Angular 1.5`, `TypeScript` and `googleapis@2.1.7`.

When I try to import it:

```
import * as gapi from 'googleapis';
```

I get this error:

> Error: The NodeJS "child_process" module is not available in the
>   browser.

Which I know is for protection, so what am I doing wrong here? I'm importing `googleapis` the same way I import everything else and the error I get comes from the Google Library itself:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Thanks!